# Committing to SharedPreferences on button press

Tags: java, android

Is there any reason this code shouldn't work? Most of the time it works, but if it's the first time the app is opened, it won't. I get a NullPointerException in the ManageBaby1/NewBabyProfile Activity when I try and call profileSelected. Then if I re-open the app and select the the other button (say I clicked on babyOneButton the first time and click on babyTwoButton the second) everything works fine. I can even go back and click on babyOneButton again and it'll work fine. For some reason it's not getting written correctly when the button is pressed?

```
public void babyOneButtonClick(View view) {

    profileSelected = "babyOne";

    if (babyOneProfile.contains("name")) {
        generalPrefsEditor.putString("profile_selected", profileSelected).commit();
        Intent goToManageBaby1 = new Intent(this, ManageBaby1.class);
        startActivity(goToManageBaby1);
    } else {
        generalPrefsEditor.putString("profile_selected", profileSelected).commit();
        Intent goToNewBabyProfile = new Intent(this, NewBabyProfile.class);
        startActivity(goToNewBabyProfile);
    }
```

}

```
public void babyTwoButtonClick(View view) {

    profileSelected = "babyTwo";

    if (babyTwoProfile.contains("name")) {
        generalPrefsEditor.putString("profile_selected", profileSelected).commit();
        Intent goToManageBaby1 = new Intent(this, ManageBaby1.class);
        startActivity(goToManageBaby1);
    } else {
        generalPrefsEditor.putString("profile_selected", profileSelected).commit();
        Intent goToNewBabyProfile = new Intent(this, NewBabyProfile.class);
        startActivity(goToNewBabyProfile);
    }
```

If you need any more information or code snippets please let me know - this has been bugging me for a while but I've been working around it because I can't for the life of me figure it out...

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the code in ManageBaby1 where the exception is being thrown.

```
        generalPrefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.general_preferences), 0);
    generalPrefsEditor = generalPrefs.edit();

    profileSelected = generalPrefs.getString("profile_selected", "profileSelected");

    if (profileSelected == "babyOne") {
        babyProfile = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.baby_one_profile), 0);
    } else if (profileSelected =="babyTwo") {
        babyProfile = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.baby_two_profile), 0);
    }

    editor = babyProfile.edit();
```

But if I take away the if statements (that require profileSelected be written in MainActivity) it works fine all the time. For some reason it's just not working the first time I click the button.

Comment: Which place is the `NullPointerException` thrown? Post your logcat if possible!

Comment: I edited the code into my OP. The exception is pointing to editor = babyProfile.edit(); as the IF statements aren't working because profileSelected isn't getting written correctly the first time I press the button for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look and have a pretty good idea I know what the problem is.  When you do the first set of profileSelected  compares neither match because your default value of profileSelected = generalPrefs.getString("profile_selected", "profileSelected"); is the string profileselected.  It doesn't equal either option and as a result BabyProfile is never assigned a value and is thus null.

Another problem is you should never ever ever ever use == to compare strings.  You should always use String.equals().  Ie in this case it would be profileSelected.equals("babyOne").

Answer (score 0):

Did you put this code in `onCreate`?

```
generalPrefsEditor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor pref_editor = generalPrefsEditor.edit();
```

I think that is the place you are getting `NullPointerException`

Comment: Yep, it's there. I edited the code into my OP. But if I take away the if statements (that require profileSelected be written in MainActivity) it works fine all the time. For some reason it's just not working the first time I click the button.